# Get Binary image usin histogram colour range in python

Tags: python, threshold

I want to get a binary image using threshold.
In my histogram below 50 and above 150 want to set 0 and 50-150 range set as 255.
how to do in python?

Comment: You'll have to show us the code you have so far to get any kind of meaningful answer.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. SO is not a coding service. Try to give some of your code and explain clearly what are your problem. Probably you have seen how to access a table in python and this can be a starting point.

Comment: ret,thresh2 = cv2.threshold(g,50,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)   only give below the 50 are white and above 50 are black also        ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(g,150,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY )  give above 150 values are white and below 150 values black , but i want 50-150 range is white and others are black.